# Vim C C++ syntax highlighting

Tags: c++, c, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

In the latest [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29):

Is there a way to define a '{' such that it's ignored by the C/C++ compiler (g++) but treated like a '{' in Vim synatx highlighting?

I've tried `//{` but it's ignored by Vim too.

Comment: Urgh. You're not doing a fragment include or macro, are you...

Comment: Could you state the version of vim, "latest" is vague. Can you give a reason behind this? At face value it sounds kind of strange if not a "bad idea". Possibly there is a better way to achieve your actual goal.

Comment: Get it working on any recent version of vim > 7.0 and I'll make it work on mine.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of syntax highlighting is to help indicate how the compiler will interpret your code. For example, if you miss a closing quote on a literal string, the syntax highlighting helps you to identify where you did that.

You're asking for a vim feature to do something that it's expressly designed to *avoid* doing.